# is specifying provider via Security.addProvider() and Cipher.getInstance() redundant?

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I feel like `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())` should eliminate the need to do `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding", "BC")`. That that second parameter for `Cipher.getInstance` ought to only be specified if you're *not* already doing `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())`. Is that a correct assessment?

Comment: No. When you add a provider you may be *adding* a source for say `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding`, so you need to specify which source.

Comment: In particular, `Security.addProvider` adds to the _end_ of the list, and 99.9999% of the time `SunJCE` will be earlier in the list, and will be selected for a call that _omits_ the second parameter. Note the overload with `String` second parameter _only_ works for providers in the list (but not necessarily first), while that with `Provider` second parameter works for providers whether or not they're in the list; [compare the two javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getInstance(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))

Comment: I have to say that most of the questions on stackoverflow that use the JCA API *and* specify a provider are based on faulty assumptions. Specifying a particular provider obviously reduces portability. You should only specify a provider when there is something unique about that provider that you must have. For example, a particular provider may support more secure hardware, may have a side-channel free implementation, may be faster, or may not exhibit a bug that one of the Oracle/OpenJDK providers does.